# Email template variable, image src attribute issue with gmail (in Django)

Tags: django, gmail, html-email

I am having this problem and I have seen similar questions but I can't find an exact solution to this.
I have an ecommerce site (written in Django) and I am sending out the order confirmation email, with the product image.
The product image changes according to the product that is bought by the customer, and all images are hosted on aws s3 and are public.

I am testing the app and it works in mac email app, while in the browser, when I check my gmail account the product image is not being displayed. All other images (hosted as well on aws s3, same bucket) are shown with no problems in the email.

The issue is generated by some sort of gmail handling, because I fill in the src attribute in the email template programmatically ({{ product.get_image_url}}), but gmail adds some extra characters, so that the final part of the src link looks like this:
/%0D%09%09%096-bottle-img.png
instead of
/6-bottle-img.png

The rest of the long link (the first part) is correct.

So, can anyone tell me what gmail is doing here? In my mac email app all looks good! There is no mistreating of the link. I guess this has to do with Django's template syntax, as gmail does not like the "{{ " before the variable. If I hard code this with the full aws s3 link for the src attribute, all works fine.

What is a good solution to this? I will implement more and more products, so I can't hard code the link.

Thanks,
Vittorio

Comment: upon sending an email, your app renders the email template and then send a pure **html** output to `gmail` or `outlook` whatever .. that means `gmail` wont render a `DTL`  expressions ( `{{ . . }}` synthax). Can you show us the code of `get_image_url()` function in your `Product` model ? i think there's extra blanc characters

Comment: Hi @cizario.
This is what my method returns:
output = '''https://**************/{}-bottle-img.png'''.format(self.number_of_bottles)
And this is what I have in the template <img src="{{ product.get_image_url }}">.
The thing is that if I use a hard-coded src attribute , everything works just fine.

Comment: if you go to https://www.urldecoder.org/ and decode `/%0D%09%09%096-bottle-img.png` you will see that there are some extra blanc characters ?

Comment: Yes, but those characters only appear if I inspect the img element in the gmail email in the browser, they are not there in the mac email app for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you don't need a `docstring` and just use a **double-quoted** string

refer to this thread about when to use docstrings https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/33489/when-documenting-python-when-should-i-use-docstrings-and-when-should-i-use-comm

change your function

```
output = '''https://**************/{}-bottle-img.png'''.format(self.number_of_bottles
```

to

```
output = "https://**************/{}-bottle-img.png".format(self.number_of_bottles
```

let me know if this solves you issue with super-flue blanc characters

Comment: Oh yeah this worked. I used the ''' because it was a long link, changing to double-quoted string did the trick.
Thanks! @cizario